# What is the name of the Google+ HTTP user agent?

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-plus

I am trying to share the title, description, etc. of my page on Google+, Facebook, etc.

I have the following code in CodeIgniter to check sessions, and to skip skip session checking if the user agent is Facebook scraping my pages. I am trying to do same for Google+. For this, I need to know the HTTP user agent name of Google+ and how to skip it in this code.

```
 if(!$this->session->userdata('client_id') && !strstr( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'facebookexternalhit'))
    {
        redirect('client/login/index', 'refresh');
        exit;
    }
```

Comment: Someone who's been on this site as long as you have really should now how to use capital Is and where to put question marks.

Answer (score 3):

The [officially documented user agent](https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/#faq-snippet-useragent) will contain `Google (+https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/)`.

Answer (score 1):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/19418450/413531:

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:6.0) Gecko/20110814 Firefox/6.0 Google (+https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/)"
```

But keep in mind that there is no official page declaring the user agent which is typically a sign to not rely on the user agent string. See [the answer from Google employe Jenny Murphy](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-plus-developers/BlqkRILGWDs)

> I recommend against filtering by the user agent. The user agent for
>   the +1 button's crawler is something that may change at any time
>   without notice.
>
> That being said, based on a little php script that I hacked up, it
>   looks like the user agent is currently: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1;
>   rv:6.0) Gecko/20110814 Firefox/6.0
>
> Cheers, Jenny